# How to get PLY to ignore case of a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, ply

I'm working on a simple translator from SQL INSERT statements to a dataset XML file to be used with [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org).

My current definition looks like this:

```
def t_INSERT(token):
    r'INSERT\s+INTO'
    return token
```

Now, I want to support case insensitive commands of SQL, for example, accept all of `INSERT INTO`, `Insert Into`, `insert into` and `iNsErT inTO` as the same thing.

I wonder if there is a way to PLY use `re.I` so that it will ignore the case, or yet another alternative to write the rule that I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inject flags into regexp using `(?)` syntax. Try `'(?i)INSERT\s+INTO'`, it adds the flag to ignore case.

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `lex.py` uses the `re` module to do its pattern matching. 
If you need to supply optional flags to the re.compile() function, use the reflags option to lex. For example:

```
lex.lex(reflags=re.UNICODE)
```

This information is extracted from [documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) sections 4.3 and 4.20

In your case, you can pass [re.IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) to lexer:

```
import re
lex.lex(reflags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Your code is more readable if you pass flags this way.